# How to store a variable in Javascript for different page accesses

Tags: javascript

I've written a javascript code to embed on my Google site (through Google Gadget Editor)
It is a survey!

I would like to store a number, so every time another user access the page, they see the last user final result.

It is possible without using databases?

Thank you so very much in advance

Comment: do you mean without a server, or with a server, but without a database?

Answer (score 3):

No. HTTP is inherently stateless.  You need to do something server side to push results like that to a web page.

If you are using javascript, you can keep a running count, but every time a user refreshes the page, the count gets reset.  Plus, the count is local only to that browser.  So if you wrote to a cookie, the count would only be available to that browser.

Comment: And what steps shall I take to do that?
How can I push the results to server?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should try and find external storage, maybe use a free survey from other sites

Answer (score -2):

Yes. There's a few different routes. I think you could store the data you want in a file. Then have JS read the file to get the data. Could be XML. Then when the next survey is complete have JS add a new entry or overwrite the xml file. Hey don't downvote if you don't understand. You can use JS to make an AJAX call to get the php or have php do the original parse of the file. It is possible to do without a database as was the question.

Comment: javascript can't write files, and even if it could, this would only show the count on one browser....

Comment: you can't modify a file on the server with js

Comment: You can parse it out with PHP and hand that to JS or ajax